Improve performance of getParsedProgramAccounts for StakeAccount
Using the code outlined https://solanacookbook.com/references/staking.html#get-stake-amount
I am finding the getParsedProgramAccounts call is slow for the StakeProgram, taking approximately 4 minutes on a our RPC node/validator which runs on a 24C/48T 255GB machine using NVMe drives.
We have the program-id and spl-token-owner account indexes setup on our validator.
Looking for suggestions to improve performance
const allStakeAccounts = await connection.getParsedProgramAccounts(
  StakeProgram.programId,
  {
    filters: [
      {
        memcmp: {
          offset: 12, // number of bytes
          bytes: wallet.publicKey.toBase58(), // base58 encoded string
        },
      },
    ],
  }
);


Maybe check this PR https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/pull/629#issuecomment-2067049045 and contact the guys who worked on that issue?

The call is trying to filter through all stake accounts, which is on the order of 1 million accounts. Unfortunately, this will take a long time no matter what using the standard RPC node.
If you want it to go faster, you can cache the results in a different database and add an index on the data slice that you want to search on. You can even develop a Geyser plugin which takes in all account changes to keep your separate database up to date.
More information about Geyser at https://docs.solanalabs.com/validator/geyser
Or you can hack the RPC service to add a new index for that slice that you care about within stake accounts. It would be some work, but you can start by following how the SPL Token indices work at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/a108498af172bb405ba7c35840a09c86df2ad939/accounts-db/src/accounts_index.rs#L170
